# Compare Elements in Array for While Loop - Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, csv, while-loop

I am attempting to create a script to read a CSV, then perform some operations on the contents where the first field are similar. Right now I'm stuck on trying to set up the second While loop to compare the current element to the next one.

I'm fairly new to this, because I wasn't getting anywhere trying this in Java. I can't seem to find a combination of commands that will let the loop work.

Some things I've tried are:

`While($csv[$count].ip -eq $csv[$count++].ip)`

`While((diff $csv[count].ip $csv[$count++].ip) = true)`

`While($csv[$count].ip = $csv[$count++].ip)`

Comment: Any code to show? It would help.

Comment: Tough to tell you what you are doing wrong if we don't know what you are doing...

Comment: Just updated my main message with some examples.

Comment: Update your question with a few sample CSV lines and explain what you are trying to compare and why. Make it possible for readers to precisely reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use $count++ unless you want to actually change the value of $count itself.  Instead use $count + 1 as the array index

```
$count = 0
while($count -le $csv.Count){
    if($csv[$count].ip -eq $csv[$count + 1].ip){
        # Do your stuff here
    }
    $count++
}
```

Comment: That solves that, but it looks like my code is ignoring variables from inside the loop even if I add script: or global:

Comment: @Binsky734 can you post more of the code? I might be able to help